Geolocation not working when accessing localhost using mobile browser
I'm creating a react app using react-hook-geolocation to get my gps location. It works fine when I tried to access using my development machine(Eg: localhost:5173).
But when I try to do the same using my mobile browser, it fails.
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(result => {
if (result.state === 'granted') {
  console.log('granted')
} else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
  console.log('Permissions requested. Waiting for user input...')
} else if (result.state === 'denied') {
  console.log('You shall not pass!!')
}

I've tried to debug with the code above and I realized that it is denied. Then I found out from https://developer.chrome.com/blog/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only which explains some features that reveals sensitive information can only work from secure website(https).

Since I can't really create a https using localhost(that's what I found out at the moment). I used port forwarding to solve this issue. I followed this guide here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/
Once everything is setup properly, you should start your react web using this command: npm run dev -- --host
And voila! It works!!!
PS: I've tripped up on enable usb debugging a few times when I setup. So play close attention to that. Make sure you notice that the Remote Target section of chrome is showing the device information or it will not work.
